# Android Studio Layout Screenshot Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-studio

Can't able to take **screenshot** of **layout** like before in **Android Studio 0.8.0**

```
Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot: com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent@4965fc96
```

Can anyone please fix this?

Your suggestions are welcome..

Comment: You might be better off asking this on the Android Studio website?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul asked same in Android Developer Tools community as well.